# Extend lua-resty-* modules and call parent function

Tags: lua, openresty

I am trying to write for each [lua-resty-redis](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis/), [lua-resty-memcached](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-memcached) and [lua-resty-mysql](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-mysql) modules a small class that extends the default module. In my child class, I want to call a function from the parent class but couldn't find a proper way no matter what inheritance documentation for Lua I've read.

For example, I want to overwrite the `connect()` function, do some stuff and call the parent's `connect()` function at some point. But how?

```
local redis = require "resty.redis"


function redis.connect(self, ...)


  -- Do some stuff here


  local ok, err = parent:connect(...)


  -- Do some other stuff here


  return ok, err
end
```

How can this be achieved?

As a note, all the above mentioned modules are structured like this:

```
local _M = { _VERSION = "0.1" }

local mt = { __index = _M }

function _M.new(self)
    return setmetatable({ foo = "bar" }, mt)
end

function _M.connect(self, ...)
    -- Connect
end

return _M
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
local redis = require "resty.redis"
local original_connect = redis.connect

function redis.connect(self, ...)


  -- Do some stuff here


  local ok, err = original_connect(self, ...)


  -- Do some other stuff here


  return ok, err
end
```